# django field local for every user

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

How can I create a field that is different for every user. For example if we have an instance of a Comment model and there is a field that is different for every user that tells if user has liked that comment. So when I map through the objects i can just check if a user has liked it. Something like a local field for every user.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You want a model `Comment` that can hold comments for any number of `Users`? Simply add an `FK` of `Users` to `Comment` then you can loop over all comments and see who liked them, or loop over all users and see specifically which comments they liked. This is a common pattern, am I missing something?

Comment: have you looked into types of fields a Django model can have when consulting Django's documentation? What have you tried so far ? You need to show any work you've done before expecting someone else to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To track which user has liked a comment, you can create a related entity.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  # The text of the comment
  text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
  # The post the comment relates to
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # The user who made the comment
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CommentLike(models.Model):
  # Indication of like. Could be something more complex
  # such as an enum or another entity.
  liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  # The user who changed the like status
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # The liked/unliked comment
  comment = models.ForeignKey(
    Comment, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADEm,
    related_name="likes",
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean field.

```
class Reaction(model.models):
like = models.booleanField(default=True)
```

You can implement your logic in view.py to trigger the field to be True when user like a comment or False we dislike.
I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking to create a UDL? Do you mean an object that stores information for analytical purposes? If so, you can simply create an empty object and add any data you wish to it using an Event Listener.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer thus the downvotes you got....although this is a comment, it still does not reference anything important in the original question.